# Can't find c++ extension library in python

Tags: python, c++

I have created a c++ extension

```
mylib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

that depends on

```
mystaticlib.a
```

that I want to use in my python package pythonpackage.cpp

The structure of my pythonpackage is as follows:

```
pythonpackage
|
+- cpp
   |    
    __init__.py
    mylib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
+- pure_python
   |     
   __init__.py
   functions.py
__init__.py
```

However if I import pythonpackage I get an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonpackage.mylib'
```

My **init**.py file (in cpp) is as follows:

```
from .mylib import *
```

Where do I need to place mylib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so? 
Do I also need to add mystaticlib.a there? 
How do I specify this in a setup file in order to automate it?

Comment: What have you used to build the c++ extension?

Comment: cmake and ninja

Comment: How are you importing pythonpackage? I assume the final __init__py in your list is inside pythonpackge, is it empty?